# How do I bin my PCA results i.e., 120 equal bins of my large data set?

Tags: pca, binning

I am a new researcher in Japan and working on my project. I am lost after reading one paper, the paper is from very good general he uses the technique of binning of PCA but I don't know how what does that mean how they do this.

Subsequently, we predicted PC1 and PC2 scores for each pixel across the entire NAM for baseline and end‐of‐century conditions. **Finally, PC1 and PC2 scores were partitioned into 120 equal bins to obtain a stratification of the climate space into smaller homogeneous units  This approach corresponds to a relatively conservative stratification of the climate gradient and therefore of associated velocity and analogue estimates**. We used a 120‐bins stratification to perform the climate exposure assessment presented here (see below), but as the precision of the climate, space stratification can largely influence climate analogue and velocity computations we also used climate stratifications of 40 and 200 bins to evaluate the sensitivity of the results to bin size.

If anyone please guide me, would be great favour on me.

Comment: Are you familiar with PCA and binning as individual concepts?

Comment: Thank you for your reply  I did the PCA and get its values of 101584 (cells per column) but  I want to do the equal Binning on it but I don't understand it actually what is this -Arun Jose

Comment: Binning simply means to create a discrete version of a continuous variable. For example, age could be between 0-100. I could bin age and create a new variable which only has (0,5,10,15....95,100) as values. So if you want to make 200 bins, then your bin interval will be (max-min)/200.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir -Arun Jose-